# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in D:\xampp\htdocs\ProyeKoperasi\views\tambah.php on line 4

Tags: php, html, sql

I got this error when trying to compile it

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\ProyeKoperasi\views\tambah.php on line 4

```
<?php
include 'Koneksi/koneksi.php';

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {//here is line number 4

    $id_koperasi = $_POST['id'];
    $nama_koperasi = $_POST['nama'];
    $alamat = $_POST['alamat'];
    $telp = $_POST['telp'];
    $hp = $_POST['hp'];
    $nama_cp = $_POST['kontak'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $nama_cp = $_POST['kontak'];
    $day1 = strtotime($_POST["tgl"]);
    $day1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $day1);
    $ket_fu = $_POST['Ket'];
    $pilih_ket = "";
    foreach ($ket_fu as $Ket) 
    {
    $pilih_ket .= $Ket . ", ";
    }
    $pilih_ket = substr($pilih_ket, 0, -2);
    $hasil_pembahasan = $_POST['Hasil'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO t_koperasi VALUES (
            '$id_koperasi',
            '$nama_koperasi',
            '$alamat',
            '$telp',
            '$hp',
            '$nama_cp',
            '$day1',
            '$pilih_ket',
            '$hasil_pembahasan')"
    ;

    if (mysqli_query($con,$query)) {
        header("location:index.php");
    }else {
        echo '<script type ="text/javascript">alert("Data gagal ditambahkan");</script>;';
    }
}

include 'views/v_tambah.php';
```

?>

Comment: highlight line number 4

Comment: i highlited the line 4

Comment: do you have anything before if condition ?

Comment: i think, before line number 4 you missed `;` semicolon.. (when you missed `;` or curly braces `{` or `}` then this error occur). also check this file code `koneksi.php`

Comment: i didn't miss the semicolon and i already use the Koneksi.php before and it doesnt give error like this

Comment: show your `koneksi.php` code. i'm sure this error belongs to `brackets` or `semicolon`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```html
if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) && ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "POST")) { //Line 4
```

if that doesn't work, the file that is in require has a code problem or may you didn't add all the code, because I didn't find a sintax problem